# Is there a way to keep LaTeX citation keys in .tex file when knitting r-markdown to PDF

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I am writing an article in r-markdown and would like to keep the .tex file for the submission via

```
title: "My title"
author: "My name"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
abstract: "My abstract"
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  word_document: default
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
bibliography: bibfile.bib
```

Everything works fine knitting to PDF and even the .tex file looks good, but the reference keys disappeared.
Is there a way to automatically convert the citation keys from the r-markdown file, like `[@smith1995]` to the .tex file, like `\cite{smith1995}` and create the corresponding references?

I am running `R version 4.0.3` and `pandoc 2.5` on `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)`

All R packages are updated to the most recent version:

```
 attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] texreg_1.37.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.4.2            viridis_0.5.1         tidyr_1.1.2        tidygraph_1.2.0       viridisLite_0.3.0     splines_4.0.3        
[7] foreach_1.5.1         ggraph_2.0.3          network_1.16.1        assertthat_0.2.1      yaml_2.2.1            robustbase_0.93-6    
[13] ggrepel_0.8.2         backports_1.2.1       pillar_1.5.0          lattice_0.20-41       quantreg_5.85         glue_1.4.2           
[19] digest_0.6.27         polyclip_1.10-0       colorspace_1.4-1      htmltools_0.5.1.1     cowplot_1.1.1         Matrix_1.3-2         
[25] plyr_1.8.6            conquer_1.0.2         lpSolve_5.6.15        pkgconfig_2.0.3       broom_0.7.5           SparseM_1.78         
[31] purrr_0.3.4           ergm_3.11.0           scales_1.1.1          tweenr_1.0.1          sna_2.6               MatrixModels_0.4-1   
[37] ggforce_0.3.2         tibble_3.0.6          mgcv_1.8-33           generics_0.1.0        farver_2.0.3          ggplot2_3.3.3        
[43] ellipsis_0.3.1        cli_2.3.1             splitstackshape_1.4.8 magrittr_1.5          crayon_1.3.4          statnet.common_4.4.1 
[49] evaluate_0.14         mcmc_0.9-7            fansi_0.4.1           doParallel_1.0.16     nlme_3.1-152          MASS_7.3-53          
[55] rem_1.3.1             vegan_2.5-6           tools_4.0.3           data.table_1.14.0     lifecycle_0.2.0       matrixStats_0.58.0   
[61] stringr_1.4.0         MCMCpack_1.5-0        trust_0.1-8           munsell_0.5.0         cluster_2.1.0         compiler_4.0.3       
[67] rlang_0.4.10          grid_4.0.3            iterators_1.0.13      rstudioapi_0.11       igraph_1.2.6          rmarkdown_2.7        
[73] gtable_0.3.0          codetools_0.2-18      DBI_1.1.1             reshape2_1.4.4        graphlayouts_0.7.1    rDNA_2.1.18          
[79] R6_2.5.0              gridExtra_2.3         rle_0.9.2             knitr_1.31            dplyr_1.0.4           utf8_1.1.4           
[85] permute_0.9-5         rJava_0.9-13          stringi_1.5.3         parallel_4.0.3        Rcpp_1.0.6            vctrs_0.3.6          
[91] xfun_0.21             DEoptimR_1.0-8        tidyselect_1.1.0      coda_0.19-4
```

Comment: Do you add the `bibliography` key in the YAML section? https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_bibliographies_and_citations.html

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera yes, I did and the pdf (as well as the .html and even the .docx) output looks nice and has the correct references. Just in the .tex file are no citation keys. The citations here are plain text, like (Smith 1995) instead of `\cite{smith1995}`

Comment: Would you mind editing the post and adding the full specification of YAML and the version info of R, its packages and Pandoc?

Comment: The latest pandoc version is [2.11.4](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.11.4) as of 2021/02/27. Yours may be too old to get the citation commands of LaTeX (I think Pandoc Ver. 2.5 uses `pandoc-citeproc`, which is deprecated and marks up `@mention` when producing .tex from .[R]md, if I correctly understand...?). [One chapter of R Markdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-pandoc.html) guides you to use Pandoc version(s) not bundled with the RStudio IDE. Could you report even if the problem persists after upgrading Pandoc?

Comment: Sadly, the problem persists... I also tried xelatex and lualatex, but no difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution... Changing the citation-package worked. The default `pandoc-citeproc` seems not to create the citation-key in the .tex file, but `natbib` does. I simply changed it with:

```
pdf_document:
  keep_tex: yes
  latex_engine: xelatex
  citation_package: natbib
```

Now the .Rmd citations, like `[@Smith1995]`, are converted to `\citep{Smith1995}` in the corresponding .tex file.
Another option might be `biblatex`.