# Equivalent of \usepackage[round]{natbib} in Rmarkdown yaml

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown, tex, citations

This question is related to [Is there a way to keep LaTeX citation keys in .tex file when knitting r-markdown to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66386640/is-there-a-way-to-keep-latex-citation-keys-in-tex-file-when-knitting-r-markdown). Using `natbib` and `xelatex` resulted in in-text citations with square parentheses, such as [First et al., 2020] but I need round parentheses: (First et al., 2020). Switching around different latex engines or `pdf_document` or `pdf_document2` does not change this behavior.

I prefer `pdf_document2` to accommodate some of my tables better than what `pdf_document` does. Here is my `yaml`

```
title: "abc"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: true
    toc: false
    latex_engine: lualatex
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: ref.bib
csl: apa-no-ampersand.csl
```

As stated here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/466819/use-round-brackets-instead-of-square-brackets-in-natbib-citations, I can edit my .tex file to set the parenthesis style, upload it to a tex processing program, then download the pdf, but that's quite inefficient.

Any leads to how to render in-text citations in round parentheses straight from R are much appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a compilable [mre] that actually contains a citation to test?

Comment: You probably want to add something like `\renewcommand\NAT@open{(} \renewcommand\NAT@close{)}` to your header includes, but without [mre] to test, that's just a guess...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify your `natbiboptions`. If you use BibLaTeX, then you can set `biblatexoptions`. If you want to specify multiple options, use a list notation with   `-` (two-space indent and hyphen). If you want to comment out an option, use `#`.

```
title: "abc"
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2: 
    keep_tex: true
    toc: false
    latex_engine: lualatex
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: ref.bib
natbiboptions: round
biblatexoptions:
  - sortcites = true
  - sorting = nyt
  - backend = biber
  # - maxcitenames = 2
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation.